# How to draw public transport route using google map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working with the Android project. I want to draw the route between two points which is showed public transport routes like bus and train, not the shortest route. I am using google direction API and google map API.

I want to just make it like google map where they show the suggestion of bus and times like this when we choose locations.

is there any special API for public transport route?

Comment: Try **Google map Waypoints** for more check [this](http://www.androidtrainee.com/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

Answer (score 0):

> you can use mode parameter in directions api like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
origin=place_id:ChIJ685WIFYViEgRHlHvBbiD5nE
&destination=place_id:ChIJA01I-8YVhkgRGJb0fW4UX7Y
&mode=transit
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Travel Modes  When you calculate directions, you may specify the    transportation mode to use. By default, directions are calculated as    driving directions. The following travel modes are supported:

- driving (default) indicates standard driving directions using the
  road network.
- walking requests walking directions via pedestrian    paths &
  sidewalks (where available).
- bicycling requests bicycling    directions via bicycle paths &
  preferred streets (where available).
- transit requests directions via public transit routes (where
  available). If you set the mode to transit, you can optionally
  specify either a departure_time or an arrival_time. If neither time
  is specified, the departure_time defaults to now (that is, the
  departure time defaults to the current time). You can also optionally
  include a transit_mode and/or a transit_routing_preference.